# Extra white lines/pixels

Tags: css, lines

I have a webpage - http://bit.ly/YHFX5B and if you take a look at the footer you will see that there are a few extra white pixels/lines after it. I can't understand where they are coming from.

Please advice where they could be coming from.

Thank you,
Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's caused by padding in this style:

```
#footer a {
   padding: 4px 4px 4px 0;
}
```

change it to

```
#footer a {
    padding: 4px 4px 2px 0
}
```

Comment: so simple) I don't know how I did not notice it. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

on `#footer` change padding to

```
padding: 20px 0 15px 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your `#footer` element:

```
#footer {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```